# React babel and require configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, babeljs

I'm trying to setup Spring project which uses React and Thymeleaf. 
I've also have added the requirejs and I'm tryign to run everything. 
I managed how to run everything with using

```
React.createClass
```

And now I'm trying to do it more 'react' way, so with usage of JSX, for example

```
<CommentForm />
```

and with react components written like this:

```
class CommentForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that to make it work I need to setup the babel library, and I have no idea how can I do that properly.
I read a lot of article in the google but all of them were set up on for node.js or webpack (this is also some kind of server, am I right?)

Do you know maybe what should I use to configure that properly? And include everything?
Let me know if you need any of my files, then I will put some code here.

Comment: I think using Node would be the best option. Then you can use the babel command line tool or webpack or gulp or whatever to transform your JavaScript. Also.. this day in age using Node is kind of a given for JavaScript development. It's worth it!

Comment: Maybe my understanding is very wrong, but isn't 'using node' equivalent to setting up a node server and hosting the node app on that node js server? Im not a frontend developer, but I always thought that if somebody was using node.js, then it meant that app is pure frontend (maybe with some backend endpoints). Am I right? What I want to ask is that: Can I use node also to include dependencies and build modular app ?

Comment: Node is a JavaScript runtime engine that runs on your desktop. A server is a common use case, but an equally common use case is to setup your build pipeline (transforming, minification, file manipulation)

Comment: hmmm so in such case I need to make a deep dive in the articles which I have found previously. thank you azium

Comment: You don't need to get too deep if you don't want. 1) install node https://nodejs.org/ 2) install babel https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli

Comment: Please go through https://webpack.github.io at once. It has really good documentation which will help you set up everything properly

Comment: If you're using requirejs, you can use the requirejs-babel plugin: https://github.com/mikach/requirejs-babel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, after comments from user azium I've managed how to do that.
So I've got a structure:

```
js / 
       components
           comment/
               comment-box.js
       node_modules/
       lib/
       app.js
       webpack.config.jsx
       package.json
```

And here is webpack.config.jsx:

```
'use strict';
import path from 'path';

module.exports =  {
    entry: './app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    }
};
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "app",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.3.13",
    "react": "^0.14.5",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.5",
    "rest": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015",
      "stage-3"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

And here is an example component:

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import CommentList from './commentList';
import CommentForm from './commentForm';
import client from './../../lib/client';
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
        handleCommentSubmit(comment)
        {
            var comments = this.state.data;
            comments.push(comment);
            this.setState({data: comments}, function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.props.url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: comment,
                    success: function (data) {
                        this.setState({data: data});
                    }.bind(this),
                    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            });
        }

        getCommentsFromServer()
        {
            client({method: 'GET', path: this.props.url}).done(response => {
                this.setState({data: response.entity._embedded.comments});
            });
        }
        componentDidMount()
        {
            this.getCommentsFromServer();
        }
        render()
        {
            return (
                <div className="commentBox">
                    <h1>Comments</h1>
                    <CommentList data={this.state.data}/>
                    <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default CommentBox;
```